# SetRegion stops working after I move MkMapView into a TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, ios7, mkmapview

I created a custom tableCell which is derived from TableViewCell. It only contains on property which is a MkMapView.

In the ViewDidLoad I did this.

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//Accessing mapView

```
MapViewTableCell *mapViewCell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MapViewCell"];
self.mapView = mapViewCell.mapView;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

}`

Under this tableViewCell I have this 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *mapView;`

So in the rest of the code I am accessing the mapView through the same way I was accessing it which is `self.mapView`.

But after that I just find that although through NSLog I cannot see anything wrong with my self.mapView object, its setRegion simply doesn't work and I could not update any annotation on the mapView any more.

Has anybody find such issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dequeue a cell outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as you're doing in your `viewDidLoad` method, that cell won't get every reused because the table view isn't managing it's life-cycle. Therefore, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you're getting a new "MapViewCell" instance.

Assuming you will only ever have one map view in your table, your best bet is to do one of the following:

1. Instantiate the map view in your view controller and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, add it to the cell.
2. Instead of dequeuing the map view cell, just instantiate one that you keep a reference to in your view controller and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, always return that cell.

Comment: Thank you so much @Timothy. You rock. What I actually did was I instantiated the MkMapView in side ViewDidLoad and add it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.